# Tiled - move all tiles

Tags: html5, tilemap, html-canvas, tiles

I'm making a map in Tiled.

I quickly ran out of room in the north of my map and would like to "shift" the tiles down. I'd prefer not to have to redo each of the tile layers.

Is this possible?

This is a picture of my minimap. I'd like to move them down around the red square.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose the selection tool at the top, select all the tiles you want to move then press ctrl + x to cut and press ctrl + v to paste it where you want.

Comment: could you choose that as the answer?